# Get all Google Script Triggers and remove them

Tags: google-apps-script, gs-installable-triggers

Is there a way to get (and change/remove) all Triggers from all documents in Google Script, as if I opened `Script Editor -> Edit -> All your triggers` ?

**Update:**

I added a few test triggers and tried to loop all the spreadsheet files as it is said by [Pierre-Marie Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45280323/8165331):

```
function getAllSpreadsheetTriggers()
{
    var files = DriveApp.getFilesByType('application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'),
        spreadsheets = [],
        triggers     = [];

    while(files.hasNext())
        spreadsheets.push( SpreadsheetApp.openById(files.next().getId()) );

    for (var i = 0; i < spreadsheets.length; i++)
    {
        triggers = ScriptApp.getUserTriggers( spreadsheets[i] );
        Logger.log(triggers);
    }
}
```

But `.getUserTriggers()` always return an empty array. I read [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36762427), the last answer is *"We decided not to take action on this issue. Triggers always belong to a particular script and are not accessible to other scripts. The documentation has been clarified to make this clear."*

It turns out that can't it be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the trigger from your docs/forms/spreadsheets with the [getUserTriggers(document)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getUserTriggers(Document)), [getUserTriggers(forms)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getusertriggersform) and [getUserTriggers(spreadsheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getusertriggersspreadsheet) methods, but it will return only the trigger for the specify file. <s>So you'll need to loop on all the files if you want to modify the triggers from all your Drive's file</s>.

Also, you can't modify trigger by code, but you can delete a trigger ([deleteTrigger(Trigger) method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#deleteTrigger(Trigger))) and create a new one (see [TriggerBuilder class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder)).

**Edit:** 
As [FLighter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8165331/flighter) point it, you can't get the triggers from another script that the one you're running. I should have read the documentation with more attention:

> Gets all installable triggers owned by this user in the given
>   document, for this script or add-on only. **This method cannot be used
>   to see the triggers attached to other scripts.**

So, to anwser the original question, no, you can't. You can made some code for each script you've got, but it will require to be trigger manually.

Comment: Please, can you comment my updated question? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just so you are aware, in addition to Pierre-Marie Richard's response, you can only delete the triggers you created on a document, you won't be able to delete the triggers created by other users. Any user with edit access can create a trigger on a document but that trigger can only be manipulated by that user.